# Why do my other class functions and variables become undefined after a jQuery click event triggers one of my es6 class functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined-reference, jquery-events, es6-class

I am running an es6 class function to redesign my authentication page. When the user clicks on the "register now" link, the `showRegisterSection` function is supposed to run so that it switches from the login section to the register section of the auth page. However, the problem is that when I try to access local variables that were initialized in the constructor function and the other functions of the class to perform some redesigning tasks, the browser console returns:

> "functionName is not a function"

for functions and

> "undefined"

value for variables.

I have tried different functions and searched for solutions online but to no avail. Furthermore, if I copy the code inside the function and paste them into my event handler, `showRegisterSection`, or re-assign the variables within the event handler, everything works as intended.

Bear in mind that the first function that designs the login section called, 
`ShowLoginSection` works just fine and isn't called from an event. It is also the function where the click event that calls `showRegisterFunction` is setup.

The code is provided below:

```
    removeElement,
    insert_custom_social_login_before_target_Element
 } from './util';

export default class GulaitAuth{
    //if the isLogin variable is true, then we set up the login part else, we set up the register part
    constructor(isLoginSection, loginForm){
        this._isLoginSection = isLoginSection;
        this._loginForm = loginForm;
        this.initLocalVars();
    }

    /**
     * This function initializes local variables to their supposed values
     * except those passed in on creation of class obj.
     * This is due to an unknown issue where variables simply get reset  to undefined
     */
    initLocalVars(){
        this._loginDiv = document.querySelector('.woocommerce #customer_login').firstElementChild;
        this._registerDiv = document.querySelector('.woocommerce #customer_login').lastElementChild;
        this._myAccHeader = document.querySelector( '.woocommerce-account #main #contents header h2' );
        this._socialLoginContainer = document.querySelector( '#customer_login .apsl-login-networks.theme-2.clearfix' );
        this._authPageLoginForm = document.querySelector( '.woocommerce-page #customer_login form.login' );
    }

    setupAuthPage(){
        //setup the authentication page
        //css styles for Auth page if the loginForm exists on the page
        if( this._loginForm ){
            //remove header "MY ACCOUNT" from DOM
            removeElement(this._myAccHeader);

            //center the auth div
            jQuery('body.page-id-29 .container .row.sidebar-row').css('text-align', 'center');

            //style the Auth div - container
            jQuery('.woocommerce-account #contents').css({
                'max-width' : '38.5em',
                'display': 'inline-block',
                'text-align': 'initial',
                'padding': '1.5em',
                'border-top' : '.15em solid #DF1F26e5'
            });

            if( this._isLoginSection ){
                this.showLoginSection();
            } else {
                this.showRegisterSection();
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Show Login or Register Section based on _isLoginSection variable
     */
    showLoginOrRegister(){
        if(this._isLoginSection){
            //edit the login div
            jQuery(this._loginDiv).css( {'min-width' : '100%', 'padding' : '0', 'display' : 'block'} );

            //hide the register div
            jQuery(this._registerDiv).css( 'display', 'none' );
        } else {
            //hide the login div
            jQuery(this._loginDiv).css( 'display', 'none' );

            //edit the register div
            jQuery(this._registerDiv).css( {'min-width' : '100%', 'padding' : '0', 'display' : 'block'} );
        }

    }

    showLoginSection(){
        //show loginsection
        this.showLoginOrRegister();

        //remove full width on checkbox
        jQuery('.woocommerce #customer_login form.login input[type="checkbox"]').css('min-width', '0 !important');

        //remove extra spacing to the right
        jQuery('.woocommerce-account #main #contents .type-page').css('padding', '0');

        //row containing login and register forms is slightly pushed to the left with margin
        //this makes styling difficult as it has wierd positioning
        jQuery('div#customer_login.row').css('margin', '0');

        //remove extra space after the 'lost password?' section
        jQuery('.entry .entry-content .entry-summary').css('margin-bottom', '0');

        //remove login form margin
        jQuery('.woocommerce-page #customer_login form.login').css('margin', '0');

        //edit the login text
        jQuery('.woocommerce #customer_login h2')
        .css( { 
            'border-bottom' : '0',
            'margin-bottom' : '0',
            'padding-bottom' : '0.2em'
        } )
        .text('')
        .append(
            '<span id="login-text">Login</span><span id="or-text"> Or </span><span id="register-text">Register</span>'
        );

        jQuery('#or-text, #register-text').css( {
            'opacity' : '.2',
            'font-size' : '16px',
            'word-spacing' : '.12em',
            'font-weight' : '450'
        } );


        //Insert REGISTRATION Link after 'lost password' section
        jQuery("<p style='margin-top: 2em;'>Don't have an account? <strong id='register-link'><a href='#'>Register now</a></strong></p>")
        .insertAfter("#customer_login .login p.lost_password")
        .children("#register-link").click( this.showRegisterSection );

        //add an eventListener on the register link
        //jQuery('#register-link');

        //redesign the input form input fields
        jQuery('#customer_login .login .form-row.form-row-wide input').css( {
            'border' : '1px solid #ccc',
            'background' : 'white'
        } );

        //fb color = #1c74bc

        //Delete original social login and replace with custom version in the 
        //prefered position
        this.relocateSocialLogin();
    }

    showRegisterSection(){
        console.log('Register Link clicked');

        //set isLogin to false in order to show content as designed for the register form
        this._isLoginSection = false;

        //This function initializes local variables to their supposed values except
        //those passed in on creation of class obj. 
        //This is due to an unknown issue where variables simply get reset to undefined
        this.initLocalVars();

        //show register section
        //hide the login div
        jQuery(this._loginDiv).css( 'display', 'none' );

        //edit the register div
        jQuery(this._registerDiv).css( {'min-width' : '100%', 'padding' : '0', 'display' : 'block'} );
    }

    /**
     * Delete original social login and replace with custom version in the 
     * prefered position to fit design
     */
    relocateSocialLogin(){
        //Delete existing social login
        this._socialLoginContainer.parentNode.removeChild( this._socialLoginContainer );

        //Insert custom social login just before login form on auth page = my-account page
        insert_custom_social_login_before_target_Element( this._authPageLoginForm );

    }

}
```

Comment: Which functions exactly cause this error (`FunctionName is not a function`)?

Comment: You are importing functions and then using them by passing instance variables to them. As far as I can tell, you might have to bind your function before calling them.

Comment: @Ivan all functions are causing this error when called from the `showRegisterSection` function. For example, I tried the `showLoginOrRegister` function. Bear in mind `showRegisterSection` is called as a `.click` event handler from inside `showLoginSection` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the `this` reference in the click handler defined inside `showLoginSection()`

As written: `.children("#register-link").click( showRegisterSection );`

Either use an arrow function: `.children("#register-link").click( e => this.showRegisterSection(e));`
Then the `this` reference of whatever `this` is inside `showLoginSection()` will be retained. ( our auth instance )

The alternatives are variations of `.bind()`
So either `.children("#register-link").click( this.showRegisterSection.bind(this));` inside `showLoginSection()`

Or `this.showRegisterSection = this.showRegisterSection.bind(this);` inside `constructor(isLoginSection, loginForm){`.

You'll have to do this for all the functions that will be used as event handlers, or other situations where the function is not called as a method of `GulaitAuth` class.

Comment: Thank you for that input, let me try the bind solution, however, this was just accidentally left out. I had it before but i removed as i was experimenting.In short, adding this like so,  `.children("#register-link").click( this.showRegisterSection );` still doesn't work

Comment: My personal preference is `this.showRegisterSection = this.showRegisterSection.bind(this);` inside the constructor. This allows you to write `.children("#register-link").click( this.showRegisterSection );` inside `showLoginSection`. and remove the event the same way later.

Comment: Thank you this actually worked like a charm, its similar to what we do in react. Thanks alot